# list not shuffling python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

The Code I have here should shuffle the list that contains "ace of hearts" "two of hearts" and "three of hearts".

It retrieves them from the file perfectly well, but it won't shuffle them and simply prints the list twice. As far as I know, a list can include words - however it seems I am mistaken.

```
import random
def cards_random_shuffle():
    with open('cards.txt') as f:
        cards = [words.strip().split(":") for words in f]
        f.close()
    random.shuffle(cards)
    print(cards)
    return cards
```

Comment: @ggfdsdc what does the output of print(cards) look like?

Comment: @MatthewFitch [['Ace of Hearts', 'Two of Hearts', 'Three of Hearts']]

Comment: @ggfdsdc Ah, you have a nested list. You'll need to do random.shuffle(cards[0]) or something similar to shuffle the list of words. Alternatively make a change to the "cards = [words.strip()..." line, as the square brackets make it a nested list.

Comment: @MatthewFitch Thanks. It also prints itself twice. Any ideas?

Comment: What does cards.txt look like?

Comment: @MatthewFitch Ace of Hearts:Two of Hearts:Three of Hearts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you loop over the lines in your file `for words in f` when you actually just want to get the first line of the file.

Assuming your file looks like this:

`Ace of Hearts:Two of Hearts:Three of Hearts`

Then you only need to use the first line:

```
import random
def cards_random_shuffle():
    with open('cards.txt') as f:
        firstline = next(f)
        cards = firstline.strip().split(':')
        # an alternative would be to read in the whole file:
        # cards = f.read().strip().split(':')
    print(cards)    # original order
    random.shuffle(cards)
    print(cards)    # new order
    return cards
```

Comment: One other question- how would I select individual items in a list- I have tried cards[1,3,4] as I have been told to do but it doesn't seem to work "must be intergers not tuple" and none of the answers for that topic are clear to me

Comment: @ggfdsdc One single item would be accessible with `cards[0]` (first card). You can't pick multiple cards by index (only by slice, e.g. `cards[0:2]` first and second card) with normal lists.

Comment: [`operator.itemgetter(1, 3, 4)(cards)`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function returns a list, so there is no need for `for words in f`.

```
import random
def cards_random_shuffle():
        with open('cards.txt') as f:
            cards = []
            for line in f:
                cards += line.strip().split(":")
        random.shuffle(cards)
        print(cards)
        return cards
```

Also no need for `f.close()` with the `with open(...)` syntax.